# Program to display prime numbers

Tags: c++, function, primes

I have to make a function that uses two previously referenced inputs to display all the prime numbers between the two numbers, the inputs are called imin, and imax and the part of the code we were given was

```
cout << "Primes:";
for (int j = imin; j <= imax; j++) {
    if (is_prime(j))
    {
         cout << "  " << j;
    }
}
```

which is supposed to be supplemented by our self written function and the part I made is below

```
bool is_prime( int j)
{
    bool primes(false);
    for (int k = 2; k < j; k++)
    {        
        if (j%k == 0) // if (k mod j == 0)
        {
             primes = true;
        }
        else if (j%k !=0)
        {
            primes = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I need help in making it display only the prime numbers because right now it is displaying all of the numbers. Thanks for the help I'm new to this so hopefully I was specific enough.

Comment: If this is homework, it really should be tagged as homework.  Then we can help point you in the right directions rather than do your homework for you.

Comment: @MatBailie I was just about to comment along the same lines!

Comment: like I said, I'm new to this, I didn't even know that was an option. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to make the tag homework on it I just tried.

Comment: the homework tag is deprecated. thousands of so-users spent hours to remove it from all posts where it had been used before...

Comment: Can any of you help me with my problem or am I just going to be criticized for being new to this website?

Comment: its `return prime;` and not `return true;`! It makes your every if statement true and hence all numbers are displayed.

Answer (score 4):

The last line of your function:
**return true**

will always return true whether or not the number is prime, so that is why all the numbers are displayed. If you pass any number 'n' as an argument to **is_prime(n)**, it will always return true.

Comment: You might also want to break when you figure out its not a prime, it could reassign the variable and give a false/positive

Answer (score 2):

You have three errors that I could find:

- Number should be considered prime, unless you can prove otherwise (find a divisor) - line: `bool primes(false);`
- Number is not prime if you find a divisor - when `j%k == 0`, but in your code you have something opposite
- When you prove that a number is not prime then there is no need to continue computations

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool is_prime( int j)
{
    bool primes(true);
    for (int k = 2; k < j; k++)
    {        
        if (j%k == 0) // if (k % j == 0)
        {
             primes = false;
        }

    }
    return primes;
}

int main( void )
{
int imax = 100;
int imin = 1;

cout << "Primes:";

for (int j = imin; j <= imax; j++) {
    if (is_prime(j))
    {
         cout << "  " << j;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: when I put in return primes the output is blank.

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to write the function myself than to explain in bad English why your function is wrong.:)

```
bool is_prime( unsigned int value )
{
    bool prime = ( value == 2 ) || ( value % 2 && value != 1 );

    for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j < value / 2; j += 2 )
    {
        prime = value % j != 0;
    }

    return prime;
}
```

the for statement can be wriiten as

```
for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j * j <= value; j += 2 )
```

Comment: spasiba Vlad, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have some error into your code.

First, when j % k is equals zero, the number isn't prime.
Second, you have to handle number inf to number 2. They require special treatment.

I put some changment in your code. Please look at it :

```
bool is_prime(int j)
{
  for (int k = 2; k < j; k++)
    if (j % k == 0)
      return (false);
  if (j < 2)
    return (false);
  return (true);
}
```

Let's see how it's works with an example!

If the number (j) is less than 2 the function will skip the loop and return false. Says that the number isn't prime.

If the number (j) is higher than 2 the function will go into a loop. How does the loop work?

Assume that j is the number 5, here is the loop:

```
   if (j % k == 0) With k moving from 2 to (j - 1) so 4

   if (5 % 2 == 0) -> false, loop continue
   if (5 % 3 == 0) -> false, loop continue
   if (5 % 4 == 0) -> false, loop continue
```

Loop stop cause k is equals to j.
   Function return true, number 5 is prime.

Now assume that j is the number 10 and let's see what change:

```
  if (j % k == 0) With k moving from 2 to (j - 1) so 9

  if (10 % 2 == 0) -> true, function return false
```

Number 10 isn't prime

If you have any questions, you are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is error in your code, the prime number has only two factors that is 1 and the number itself, So the code should be as follows:

```
bool is_prime( int j)
{
    bool primes(false);
    for (int k = 2; k < j; k++)
    {        
        if (j%k == 0) // if (k mod j == 0)
        {
             primes = false;
             break; //if number is divisible in between then retrun false and break the loop
        }
        else if (j%k !=0)
        {
            primes = true;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Try the code and let me know if error occurs

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should eliminate any *even* prime candidates:

```
if (imin < 2) // no primes < 2 :
    return;

cout << "Primes:";
if (imin == 2)
    cout << "  " << i;

imin = imin + ((imin & 0x1) == 0); // advance to next odd number.
```

This allows you to test for primes with:

```
for (int j = imin; j <= imax; j += 2) // odd candidates (j > 2) only:
{
    if (is_prime(j))
         cout << "  " << j;
}
```

Be aware that there are more efficient ways to test primality if `j` is sufficiently large. However, if you want minimum code that works, it's only necessary to test for prime factors up to `floor(sqrt(j))` :

```
bool is_prime (int j)
{
    // assert (j > 2 && (j & 0x1) == 1); // j > 2, j in odd:

    int d, q, c = 0;

    for (d = 3; !c && (q = j / d) >= d); d += 2)
        c = (q * d == j); // sets c <- 1 if 'd' is a factor of 'j'

    return (c == 0); // prime (true - no 'd' factor) or composite (false)
}
```